# Get Element Position within std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

How do I get the position of an element inside a vector, where the elements are classes. Is there a way of doing this?

Example code:

```
class Object
{
  public:
    void Destroy()
    {
      // run some code to get remove self from vector
    }
}
```

In main.cpp:

```
std::vector<Object> objects;
objects.push_back( <some instances of Object> );
// Some more code pushing back some more stuff

int n = 20;
objects.at(n).Destroy(); // Assuming I pushed back 20 items or more
```

So I guess I want to be able to write a method or something which is a member of the class which will return the location of itself inside the vector... Is this possible?

EDIT:

Due to confusion, I should explain better.

```
void Destroy(std::vector<Object>& container){
  container.erase( ?...? );
}
```

The problem is, how can I find the number to do the erasing...? Apparently this isn't possible... I thought it might not be...

Comment: Write a proper comparison operator for your class that reflects the semantics you require, then use `std::find`.

Comment: Why would the Object care if it is a member of a vector, a list, or a deque?

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you just said. I need to write an `operator== (...)`  and use std::find which is some code which does what?

Comment: @BoPersson I am writing a Physics project. It is a requirement to make my code "better". (Define better, you ask?)

Comment: Having objects be aware of which container they are in is a sure way to make code *worse*.

Comment: This is not a team development project, and I assure you it will  improve the code rather than break it. I am sure I can cope with disobeying the rules they teach you on your good coding practice courses.

Comment: I'm not sure what courses you're talking about but people have been removing elements from vectors for decades now without the need for any special shenanigans.

Comment: Well there you go there are exceptions to the rule.

It is possible I could stick everything inside a "master class" which manages everything, but I think that is a very poor way of coding a universe since as far as we can tell sections of the cosmos are independent of each other, and there is no master controller. (Unless you count God, however as far as we know he doesn't involve himself in the everyday physics of the Universe or at least not in an "ideal universe".)

Comment: A more sensible and flexible solution to your problem would be to implement a notification system.  The object could have a list of subscribers to be notified of when it needs to be destroyed.  The owning container would add itself to this list through one of the object's member functions.  Then the destroy function would notify everyone on the list so they could take appropriate action, in this case, the owning container would remove the object from itself.

Comment: Yes, but this has the disadvantage that I need to implement a load of extra variables and methods, and the destroying is still being done externally by a wrapper class of sorts.

However, it is still a good solution.

Comment: Yes, but it also has the advantage of being a correct thing to do, rather than an incorrect/illogical thing to do. (your case is not exceptional, I assure you)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley if you do not understand why I am doing this, which I assure you, you do not, then you need not make your unguided opinions known. I say unguided because you have no knowledge to guide you in this discussion. I presume you have some experience in writing c++ code, but I highly doubt you have experience in writing Physics computer simulations. You tell me what qualifications you have and I anticipate I will tell you that you don't know what you are talking about in this "exceptional" case. As it turns out, you are correct in that what I am trying to do cannot actually be done,

Comment: however since I have not studied c++, I could not be sure this was the case, although I suspected it might be.

Comment: The way in which your case is not exceptional has nothing to do with it being a physics simulation.  It is non-exceptional in the sense that people in the past have wanted to give their objects a way to remove themselves from the container that was holding holding them.

Comment: And about me having no knowledge to guide me in this discussion.  It is your responsibility to provide that knowledge.  Instead of asking a question about how to implement your proposed solution, ask a question about what the actual problem is, that way others can give you advice with more appropriate solutions. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Once again @BenjaminLindley, you are talking but don't know what you are talking about. The fact that this is an exceptional case has everything to do with it being a Physics simulation. I cannot explain it to you because there is clearly no hope for you to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::find` to find elements in `vector` (providing you implement a comparison operator (`==`) for `Object`. However, 2 big concerns:

1. If you need to find elements in a container then you will ger much better performance with using an ordered container such as `std::map` or `std::set` (find operations in `O(log(N))` vs `O(N)`
2. `Object` should not be the one responsible of removing itself from the container. `Object` shouldn't know or be concerned with where it is, as that breaks encapsulation. Instead, the owner of the container should concern itself ith such tasks.

Comment: Unfortunately, it would be better if we ignored the rules of encapsulation.

Comment: Sometimes? sure. As a general rule of thumb? Definitely not. Objects should generally NOT be "aware" of the context in which they will be stored in. They can limit that context via Singletons, private constructors etc. but explicitly knowing the type of your owner is never a positive (perhaps an interfaces in some cases, but even that should be avoided when possible)

Comment: Yeah this is one of those cases, but I am not writing an interface.

Answer (score 1):

The object can erase itself thusly:

```
void Destroy(std::vector<Object>& container);
{
  container.erase(container.begin() + (this - &container[0]));
}
```

This will work as you expect, but it strikes me as exceptionally bad design. Members should not have knowledge of their containers. They should exist (from their own perspective) in an unidentifiable limbo. Creation and destruction should be left to their creator.

Comment: Yes, I feel like this is exactly what I want.

Comment: Be aware that the object no longer exists after the call to `.erase()`. So, for example, you must not reference any member variables or call any member functions. To be safe, the only thing you should do after `.erase()` is `return;`.

Comment: Also, this solution is specific to `std::vector<>` due to the pointer arithmetic. Other containers do not have contiguous objects. This won't work on `std::list<>`, `std::set<>`, etc., and may not work on `std::vector<DerivedFromObject>`.

Comment: This appears to be a risky thing to do. I can see why people are against it, however in this exceptional case, it is defiantly the correct/most logical thing to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Objects in a vector don't automatically know where they are in the vector.

You could supply each object with that information, but much easier: remove the object from the vector. Its destructor is then run automatically.

Then the objects can be used also in other containers.

---

Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class object_t
{
private:
    int     id_;
public:
    int id() const { return id_; }

    ~object_t() {}
    explicit object_t( int const id ): id_( id ) {}
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    vector<object_t> objects;

    for( int i = 0;  i <= 33;  ++i )
    {
        objects.emplace_back( i );
    }

    int const n = 20;
    objects.erase( objects.begin() + n );

    for( auto const& o : objects )
    {
        cout << o.id() << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I feel like you didn't understand the question. Destroy is a method which will do the removing.

Comment: Okay an edit was made, thanks I'll look into implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to destroy the n'th item in a vector then the easiest way is to get an iterator from the beginning using `std::begin()` and call `std::advance()` to advance how ever many places you want, so something like:

```
std::vector<Object> objects;
const size_t n = 20;

auto erase_iter = std::advance(std::begin(objects), n);

objects.erase(erase_iter);
```

If you want to find the index of an item in a vector then use `std::find` to get the iterator and call `std::distance` from the beginning.

So something like:

```
Object object_to_find;
std::vector<Object> objects;

auto object_iter = std::find(std::begin(objects), std::end(objects), object_to_find);

const size_t n = std::distance(std::begin(objects), object_iter);
```

This does mean that you need to implement an equality operator for your object. Or you could try something like:

```
auto object_iter = std::find(std::begin(objects), std::end(objects), 
  [&object_to_find](const Object& object) -> bool { return &object_to_find == &object; });
```

Although for this to work the object_to_find needs to be the one from the actual list as it is just comparing addresses.

Comment: The problem is finding what the values of n is going to be.